# What is the purpose of onMessageReceived on Android Firebase?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android app and I added Firebase so I could get notifications.

Looking into this I bumped into onMessageReceived().

Does anyone know any real life examples of how this can be used? or what's the purpose?

**Thanks for any help :)**

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever an app is in foreground/active the incoming notification goes into app which you can get from `onMessageReceived()` method, the notification will not be shown automatically, you will have to do it manually.

If the app is in background/inactive the incoming notification goes into the systems notification service which will show the notification automatically.

If you want to do both the task manually you have to send data while sending a fcm message.

or in in firebase functions you can do it like this

```
const payload = {
                data: {
                    title: "title",
                    body: `body`,
                    icon: "default",
                    sound: "default"
                }
            };

            const options = {
                priority: "high",
                timeToLive: 60 * 10
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifyAll", payload, options)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                    return error;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes so much sense now. I just didn't understood at first what would be the point of receiving the data without the notification.